# Can I return an anonymous struct from a method?

Tags: go, struct, return, return-type

Let's say I've got a struct such as:

```
type Tmp struct {
    Number int 
    Text   string
}
```

Is it possible to have a method that returns an anonymous struct? something like:

```
func (t Tmp) MyStruct() struct {
    return struct {
        myVal       string
    }{
        "this is my val"
    }
}
```

I tried the code above but I'm getting an error. Is this possible to achieve any other way?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes it's possible, but your function signature is syntactically incorrect. `struct` is a [keyword](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Keywords), not a type.

It's valid like this:

```
func (t Tmp) MyStruct() struct {
    myVal string
} {
    return struct {
        myVal string
    }{
        "this is my val",
    }
}
```

Testing it:

```
var t Tmp
fmt.Printf("%+v", t.MyStruct())
```

Output will be (try it on the [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/rrJLgP8TpLu)):

```
{myVal:this is my val}
```

As you can see, it's not very convenient as you have to repeat the struct definition in the [composite literal](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Composite_literals) when returning the value. To avoid that, you may use [named result](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Function_types):

```
func (t Tmp) MyStruct() (result struct {
    myVal string
}) {
    result.myVal = "this is my val"
    return
}
```

This outputs the same. Try this one on the [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/8JWJt_v-XZB).

But the easiest is to define a type you want to return, and everything will be simple:

```
type MS struct {
    myVal string
}

func (t Tmp) MyStruct() MS {
    return MS{myVal: "this is my val"}
}
```

Try this one on the [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/cpwpVnUOXuW).